# System audit plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, wp-admin

Is there a plugin that tracks wordpress admin settings and actions? eg when plugins are activated/deactivated, plugin settings are changed, user settings and permissions changed?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-log/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I've used plugin like that while back, but I totally can't remember its name and it was not repository-hosted (made to integrate with some third party security tool). Can't find it. :(

From repository this one seems fitting:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audit-trail/

Comment: I've used audit trail for admin access managing for a public school website and it has worked very well. That would be my suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a couple of plugins that do this. Here are two more that I know of (I'm the author the last one BTW):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-activity-monitor/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-history/