# Log Author Actions

Tags: server, logging

Is there a place where actions like post creation/deletion, page creation/deletion, modification, etc. is saved? Is this stored in the Apache logs?

If this is not saved, is there a way (plugin?) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called Audit Trail. It will pretty much log all actions for your wordpress backend such as page creation / deletion, post creation / deletion, logging in / logging out.

You can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audit-trail/

Comment: No problem. If this is your chosen answer don't forget to choose it and rate it up. :) It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has also been asked/answered here:
[System audit plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4103/system-audit-plugin)

There three more plugins are mentioned, but I can not post the links to the plugins here because I don't have a reputation good enough :)

Anyway, their names are:

- Simple History
- Admin Log
- Threewp activity monitor